# how to change web server url with listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

how to change **WEB_URL** with listview in android.
The server is based on each city and the server is changed when the city is selected.

**Constant.java**

```
public class Constant extends Activity {

/**
 * -------------------- EDIT THIS WITH YOURS -------------------------------------------------
 */

// Edit WEB_URL with your url. Make sure you have backslash ('/') in the end url
public static String WEB_URL= "http://hajaghaali.com/armaghan/";

/* [ IMPORTANT ] be careful when edit this security code  */
/* This string must be same with security code at Server, if its different android unable to submit order */
public static final String SECURITY_CODE = "";

// Device will re-register the device data to server when open app N-times
public static int OPEN_COUNTER = 50;


/**
 * ------------------- DON'T EDIT THIS -------------------------------------------------------
 */

// this limit value used for give pagination (request and display) to decrease payload
public static int NEWS_PER_REQUEST = 10;
public static int PRODUCT_PER_REQUEST = 10;
public static int NOTIFICATION_PAGE = 20;
public static int WISHLIST_PAGE = 20;

// retry load image notification
public static int LOAD_IMAGE_NOTIF_RETRY = 3;

// Method get path to image
public static String getURLimgProduct(String file_name) {
    return WEB_URL + "uploads/product/" + file_name;
}

public static String getURLimgNews(String file_name) {
    return WEB_URL + "uploads/news/" + file_name;
}

public static String getURLimgCategory(String file_name) {
    return WEB_URL + "uploads/category/" + file_name;
}
```

I want to change the server when I click on one of the items in the list.

Comment: I don't see a list view, adapter or anything like that in your posted code?

Comment: Oh yes It does not matter if the listView or button. I want to know how to change the WEB_URL address with the code

Comment: this is my app code: http://wdhweb.com/Markeet/android_project/Markeet/app/src/main/java/com/app/markeet/data/Constant.java